# Is it possible to show a vim cheatsheet like in Nano at the bottom of the page?

Tags: vim, nano

I am using Debian GNU/Linux.
Are there any options or extensions to vim that give me the possibility to display a cheat sheet in vim as shown in Nano?

Comment: Or you can type `:help` to get into help mode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to do this.  The cheatsheet that's used in Nano is built into the source code, and the editor it's modeled after, Pico, has one as well.

Vim, however, doesn't have such an option as far as I'm aware.  There are many more commands that are commonly used in Vim than in Nano.  My version of Nano lists 22 commands, and I routinely use more than that in daily editing even if you only include letters of the alphabet in normal mode, so there's not necessarily a good limited set to expose.  Part of the problem is that Vim has both actions and motions and you need to combine both to be even moderately effective, so the number of things to show is potentially very expansive.

Vim does provide a full built-in help mode which you can invoke with `:help`, possibly followed by a topic you're interested in, which makes things a little easier.  Then again, Nano also has built-in help, and it's even translated.